# Exporting a DIV that contains Tables and Highchart Graphs to PDF

Tags: javascript, c#, pdf, highcharts, export-to-pdf

I'm trying to find a tool that will allow me to export a Div section of an html page to a PDF file, and the div contains both html tables and highchart graphs.  I've not had any luck exporting both tables AND graphs.  Below is a screenshot of what my page looks like, as you can see there are tables and graphs on the same row.  I've tried using iTextSharp but it keeps omitting the graphs for some reason.  Is there a free tool out there (preferably in c# or javascript) that I can use to accomplish this?

...since I don't have a high enough reputation to post images, the layout of the html, roughly, is two "columns" of data, with the layout looking like:

div
  table       highchart
  highchart   highchart
  table       highchart
  highchart   table
  table       table
/div

Comment: This sample has Highcharts: http://www.cloudformatter.com/CSS2Pdf.SVGCharts.HighCharts. this one Highchart Stock: http://www.cloudformatter.com/CSS2Pdf.SVGCharts.highstock and tables are here: http://www.cloudformatter.com/CSS2Pdf.Demos.Tables

Comment: We use [Rotativa](https://github.com/webgio/Rotativa/blob/master/README.markdown) to print PDFs here. May can it help?

Comment: You can render table by highcharts and then export that, like [here](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions#add-data-table)